# "No data is deployed on the contact address!" Token issue

Tags: solidity, ethereum-wallet-dapp

Here is my code:

> ```
> pragma solidity 0.4.11;
>
> contract MyToken {
> string public name;
> string public symbol;
> uint8 public decimals;
> string public standard = 'RNTLcoin 0.1';
> uint256 public totalSupply;
>
> mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
>
> event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
>
> function MyToken(
>     uint256 initialSupply, 
>     string tokenName, 
>     uint8 decimalUnits, 
>     string tokenSymbol){
>     balanceOf[msg.sender] = initialSupply;              
>     name = tokenName;
>     symbol = tokenSymbol;
>     decimals = decimalUnits;    
>     }
>
>
> function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) {
>     if (balanceOf[msg.sender] < _value) throw;           // 
>     if (balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]) throw; // 
>     balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;                     // 
>     balanceOf[_to] += _value;                            //
>
>
> } }
> ```

I am running a private blockchain with Gethdev and attaching with the lastest Ethereum Wallet. However, it doesn't display any tokens being created even though the transaction is mined. I've tried using the maximum gas, minimum gas and required gas and still it doesn't work. Can anyone explain why this is happening? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What does the mined transaction do? If the contract was deployed from Ethereum Wallet you should be able to access public variables like balanceOf.

Comment: `However, it doesn't display any tokens being created even though the transaction is mined.` Could you please elaborate on how you are checking for tokens being created? And what is the result you are expecting. A contract creation transaction once mined will return the address of the contract. Are you querying this address?